# Ввод с клавиатуры и передача по межпроцессорному каналу

Tags: shell

Здравствуйте, подскажите как реализовать ввод с клавиатуры названия файлов и передача этой информации по межпроцессорному каналу в другой процесс, где сравнить данные файлы
я пробовал сделать вот так:

```
read file1 file2 
file1_second=$file1 file2_second=file2 | diff $file1_second $file2_second > file3
```

пробовал вот так:

```
read file1 file2 | diff $file1 $file2 > file3
```

но оба раза он жаловался на то, что у diff отсутствует операнд

Comment: Можно спросить, а зачем вообще передавать эти имена? В скрипте сразу после `read file1 file2` можно вызвать `diff "$file1" "$file2"`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
cat | { read file1 file2; diff $file1 $file2; }
```

Конвейер (*pipe*), это всегда новый процесс, в котором не экспортированные переменные, которые объявляет `read`, будут невидны.

И кроме того, `read` читает, а не пишет. `diff` не читает с входного потока, он ожидает аргументы, которые не найдя, т.к. `file1` и `file2` не объявлены, выводит ошибку.